AEM - Unable to resolve recaptcha enterprise bundle
I'm trying to import the following packages in my Captcha Service:
import com.google.cloud.recaptchaenterprise.v1.RecaptchaEnterpriseServiceClient;
import com.google.recaptchaenterprise.v1.Assessment;
import com.google.recaptchaenterprise.v1.CreateAssessmentRequest;
import com.google.recaptchaenterprise.v1.Event;
import com.google.recaptchaenterprise.v1.ProjectName;

However, in my AEM console, I'm still unable to resolve the bundles:
com.google.cloud.recaptchaenterprise.v1 -- Cannot be resolved
com.google.recaptchaenterprise.v1 -- Cannot be resolved
When I check the logs, I'm getting these errors:
12.09.2024 07:16:47.459 *ERROR* [FelixLogListener] Events.Framework.project-www.core FrameworkEvent ERROR (org.apache.felix.log.LogException: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve project-www.core [606](R 606.248): missing requirement [project-www.core [606](R 606.248)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.google.cloud.recaptchaenterprise.v1) Unresolved requirements: [[project-www.core [606](R 606.248)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.google.cloud.recaptchaenterprise.v1)])
org.apache.felix.log.LogException: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve project-www.core [606](R 606.248): missing requirement [project-www.core [606](R 606.248)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.google.cloud.recaptchaenterprise.v1) Unresolved requirements: [[project-www.core [606](R 606.248)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.google.cloud.recaptchaenterprise.v1)]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4398)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2308)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1566)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

In AEMaaCS build log:
2024-09-10 02:34:57.644 Analyser errors have been found 
2024-09-10 02:34:57.644 The analyser found the following errors for author and publish : 
2024-09-10 02:34:57.644 [api-regions-exportsimports] my.co.project:project-www.core:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Bundle project-www.core:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is importing package(s) [com.google.cloud.recaptchaenterprise.v1, com.google.recaptchaenterprise.v1] in start level 20 but no bundle is exporting these for that start level. (my.co.project:project-www.ui.apps:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT)

Maven build is working fine. Here's my POM setup:
(parent pom.xml)
<build>
    <plugins>
        ......
        <plugin>
            <!-- Builds the dependency as OSGi bundle -->
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Import-Package>*;resolution:=optional</Import-Package>
                    <Export-Package>
                        com.google.recaptchaenterprise.v1.*,
                        com.google.auth.*,
                        com.google.api.gax.*,
                        com.google.cloud.recaptchaenterprise.v1.*
                    </Export-Package>
                    <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime</Embed-Dependency>
                    <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <!-- Installs the build OSGi bundle into specified AEM instance's felix console -->
            <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
            <artifactId>sling-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install-bundle</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <slingUrl>http://${aem.host}:${aem.port}/system/console</slingUrl>
                        <refreshPackages>true</refreshPackages>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        ......
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-recaptchaenterprise</artifactId>
    <version>3.18.0</version>
</dependency>

(core/pom.xml)
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-recaptchaenterprise</artifactId>
</dependency>


Can you please check this document Embedding Third party dependency/OSGi bundle in AEM application hosted in AEMasCS which may resolve the issue.

Hi I have followed what was shown in that article, however, I'm still getting the issue.

What is the project archetype version? have you tried - bnd-maven-plugin instead of maven-bundle-plugin?
Post build, check you target folder - target/classes -> do you see the above exported packages and their classes copied here?
